# Swift Type Erasure attempt: "Reference to invalid associated type"

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, type-erasure

I'm doing a fabricated exercise to try to implement a type-erased container.

```swift
import Foundation

protocol MoverType {
    func move()
}
extension MoverType {
    func move() { print("\(type(of: self)) is moving") }
}

class Slithering: MoverType {}
class Walking: MoverType {}
class Trotting: MoverType {}

protocol Animal {
    associatedtype Mover: MoverType
    var mover: Mover { get }
}

class Snake: Animal {
    let mover = Slithering()
}
class Dog: Animal {
    let mover = Trotting()
}
class Human: Animal {
    let mover = Walking()
}

class AnyAnimal: Animal {  // ERROR: Type 'AnyAnimal' does not conform to protocol 'Animal'
    var _mover: () -> Mover
    init<A: Animal>(animal: A) where Mover == A.Mover {
        _mover = {
            return animal.mover
        }
    }

    // ERROR HERE: "Reference to invalid associated type "Mover" of of type "AnyAnimal"
    var mover: Mover { fatalError() }
}

let d = AnyAnimal(animal: Dog())
let s = AnyAnimal(animal: Snake())

let animals = [d, s]   // Array<AnyAnimal>
for a in animals {
    a.mover.move()
}
```

I deliberately didn't want my `AnyAnimal` container to be an `AnyAnimal<T>` container.  Because, I'd like to be able to store many `Animal` instances in an `Array<AnyAnimal>`.

However, as you can see in the code above, the compiler is complaining about the `AnyAnimal` class.  It's my understanding that the protocol requirement of `Mover` would be resolved by the generic `where` clause in the `AnyAnimal` initializer.

Please help me understand what's missing.  (Or, is it even possible to create a non-generic type-erasing wrapper in the first place?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile because the associated type needs to be resolved at compile time by providing a concrete implementation for the `Mover` protocol.

What you can do, is to also erase the `MoverType` protocol:

```swift
struct AnyMover: MoverType {
    private let mover: MoverType

    init(_ mover: MoverType) {
        self.mover = mover
    }

    func move() {
        mover.move()
    }
}

class AnyAnimal: Animal {
    let mover: AnyMover

    init<A: Animal>(animal: A) {
        mover = AnyMover(animal.mover)
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why the closure and fatalError here? There's no problem with `AnyAnimal.mover` just being a regular `AnyMover` property is there?

Comment: Valid points, @RobNapier I quickly copy+pasted the original class and only fixed the compiler errors. I should've clean the code all the way. I updated the answer. Thanks for the code review.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Cristik about adding an AnyMover type-eraser. That's the way to do literally what you're saying. But if you're down this road, you've usually mis-designed your protocols. For example, while I know this is fabricated, it's a great example of a mis-designed protocol. The Animal protocol should almost certainly be:

```
protocol Animal {
    func move()
}
```

And then your `associatedtype`, and the related problems, evaporate. And your interface makes more sense. An Animal can move. It isn't something "with a Mover." I expect that every use of this type would look pretty much identical to your example: `animal.mover.move()`. That says that `mover` is an implementation detail that callers shouldn't care about.

What else *could* you do inside a loop over `[Animal]`? How could you write generic code that used `.mover` and *didn't* call `.move`? There aren't any other methods.

I know this is fabricated, but this situation is exactly what comes up in many real cases, and you should be on the lookout for it. When you find yourself reaching for type-erasers, and especially if you start reaching for two levels of type-erasers, you need to ask if you've done something wrong. Not always, but most of the time, there is a better solution to the problem in front of you.

BTW, another approach here would be to keep Movers, but just let them be a protocol. Does the caller really want to know the difference between crawlers and slitherers? Isn't hiding that the whole goal? If so, you can go this way:

```
protocol Animal {
    var mover: MoverType { get }
}
```

And again, all the problems evaporate.

Either way, you can still automatically implement your `move()` method if there's a `mover` available. For example, you could design the protocols this way:

```
// Something that moves animals
protocol Mover {
    func move(animal: Animal)
}

// Something that has a mover
protocol MoverProviding {
    var mover: Mover { get }
}

// And of course Animals. They might be MoverProviding. They might not.
protocol Animal {
    func move()
}

// But if they *are* MoverProviding, we can use that.
extension Animal where Self: MoverProviding {
    func move() {
        mover.move(animal: self)
    }
}
```

When you type `associatedtype`, you should generally be thinking "this protocol is all about adding extra algorithms (methods and functions) to other types." If the point of the protocol is to allow heterogeneous collections, you're probably on the wrong road. Type-erasers are sometimes useful and important, but if you feel you need them a lot (and *especially* if you need them because of heterogeneous collections), you probably have a design problem.

Comment: AWESOME ANSWER.  Cristik's answer is the actual solution so I'm gonna mark is as the correct answer.  But this was hugely informative.  Thanks!